# Client Server application design patterns and protocols

Tags: design-patterns, client-server, network-protocols

I am trying to find "good practices" for designing client/server applications.

If anyone could recommend some good material to read?

Specifically how do you design an application layer protocol and make it robust, while avoiding pitfalls?

In some client/server instances like games the server is an interpreter for 
actions to be taken, can you design a protocol as to elegantly cooperate with such a design pattern?

Is there a design pattern designed for client/server applications. I was also thinking maybe a modified producer consumer pattern?

Edit: oops I realize this question can't have a definitive answer so I will give correct answer to an in-depth answer.

Thank you

Comment: may want to read up on the [reactor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern)

Comment: @Oren The description seems almost perfect, Thanks for the info

Comment: @Oren This question has been viewed quite a few times now. Do you mind adding an answer with an overview of the reactor pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned a lot from this book:

Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture

http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Patterns-of-Enterprise-Application-Architecture/9780321127426.page

there are a lot of patterns for client/server applications, and you should take the one that fits your needs.

If you don't want the book, there are also free resources in internet:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you seems like great resources, I wasn't aware there were such a thing as "enterprise application architecture". Just the type of thing I was looking for :D

Answer (score 3):

Check this, may be it can help you : [A Multi-client Server Design Pattern Using Simple TCP/IP Messaging](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3055/en/)